# Text popping in during CSS3 animation

Tags: html, css

So I built a menu and would like to be able to toggle it. I'm simply animation the width using CSS3.

```
-webkit-transition: width 1s;
transition: width 1s;
```

Now, when the menu is closed and you re-open it, the menu items "pop in", as shown here: https://gyazo.com/6dfee24687fff026e464323882770959

I think it's because the sentences are wrapping. I've tried everything to stop that from happening, to no avail.

This is my structure:

```
   <div id="menu" class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 nopad closed">
        <div id="togglemenu" class="col-xs-12 nopad">
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3 menu-icon" onclick="document.querySelector('#menu').classList.toggle('closed')">
                <div class="vertical">
                    <div>
                        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nopad menu-header col-xs-12" onclick="document.querySelector('#menu').classList.toggle('closed')">
            <div class="vertical">
                <div class="pull-right menu-toggle">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div>MENU</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 nopad">
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3 menu-icon">
                <div class="vertical">
                    <div>
                        <i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 menu-item active">
                <div class="vertical">
                    <div>Menu item</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nopad menu-header btop col-xs-12">
            <div class="vertical">
                <div>Menu divider</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS that goes along with it:

```
#menu {
    min-height: 65vh;
    background: #1c2329;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s;
    transition: width 1s;
}
    #menu div {
        text-overflow: clip;
    }

.togglemenu {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-header {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #181d21;
}
    .menu-header.btop {
        border-top: 1px solid #3de66e;
    }

.vertical {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu-icon {
    background: #1c252a;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.1vh;
    color: #3de66e;
}

.menu-item {
    background: #1c2329;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    .menu-item.active {
        border-right: 3px solid #3de66e;
    }

.menu-icon, .menu-header, .menu-item {
    height: 5vh;
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu.closed .menu-item, #menu.closed .col-md-9, #menu.closed .menu-header {
    display: none;
}

#menu.closed .menu-item div {
    display: block;
}

#menu.closed {
    width: 3vw;
}

#menu.closed .menu-part {
    display: none;
}

#togglemenu {
    display: none;
}

#menu.closed #togglemenu {
    display: block;
}
```

I was hoping someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is because of width. The parent of the icon and text need to have fixed value.